# Cannot use latest ectags with cedet

Tags: emacs, cedet

I got this error:

```
semantic-ectags-test-version: Versifon of CTags is 5.9~svn20110310.  Need at least 5.7 [2 times]
```

How do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem was fixed in the end of December. You can fix it by upgrading to latest CEDET snapshot that contains this fix, or you can change the regex that extracts the CTags version as in this [commit](https://github.com/alexott/cedet/commit/6efc2650aa2b4d42e9bea8afce41a4e5ffb74913).

P.S. I have the same version of CTags, and it works fine for me...

Comment: Thanks. It works. And one more question: May I post a feature request on that repo?

Comment: it's better to write to cedet devel mailing list. This repository is my own copy of CEDET's repo...